# Reduction from 4COL to 3COL

Tags: algorithms, complexity-theory, time-complexity

I have a problem with following task: $4COL \in PTIME \Rightarrow 3COL \in PTIME$.

Is there any elementary proof to do it?

Answer (score 1):

Your question is answered in a [blog post](http://blog.computationalcomplexity.org/2014/05/4col-le-3col-is-counter-intuitive-and.html) of Lance Fortnow. Solutions are given by [Fortnow](http://www.cs.umd.edu/~gasarch/BLOGPAPERS/3col.pdf) and by [Lovász](http://www.cs.elte.hu/~lovasz/scans/covercolor.pdf).

Comment: One can also look at the [lecture notes of Chvátal](http://users.encs.concordia.ca/~chvatal/notes/color.html) for an exposition.